# Sort CSS Declaration Order in gulp-lesshint

Tags: gulp, less, hint, gulp-less

I want to create a rule in lesshint to sort the CSS properties as per declaration order like this:

```
"sort-order": [
  [
    "font",
    "font-family"
  ],
  [
    "top",
    "position"
  ],
  [
    "color"
  ]
]
```

it's not working well. It does not throw any error.

Comment: Is this gulp-lesshint?  It doesn't look like it sorts - as a linter I wouldn't expect it to be able to sort.

Comment: Yes, its in gulp-lesshint. The code above is incorrect, so it does not sort. But even there are no errors when I run this

Comment: I'm saying that I don't think gulp-lesshint can sort.  I don't see it that it has that option.  Where did you get the "sort-order" option from?

Comment: Yes It does not have this option, I was trying to create a custom one

Comment: Do you have a link to where that option is shown?  I don't see it in the gulp-lesshint documentation.

Comment: It's not from the gulp-lesshint documentation. Something similar to it is there in stylelint

Comment: I think you need something like cssbrush or csscomb, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/cssbrush.  You can't create a new sort-order option for lesshint if it doesn't support it.

Comment: Alright. Thanks, Mark for quick replies.